# Are there non-ergodic statistical theories?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ergodicity

From what I understand, all statistical theory proceeds by assigning probabilities to microstates based off some ergodic-like assumption, and then looking at the implications of this on properties of macrostates. First of all, is this accurate?

Second of all, if true, are there examples where probabilites are assigned not by some ergodic-like assumption but some slightly more accurate assumption? I say slightly more accurate because I don't completely believe in ergodic but don't have a concrete reason why (clarification of why or why not to would also be welcome!)

The only situation I can see where a non-ergodic approach would be of use is in critical phenomena where many statistical assumptions break down but I don't know this well enough to say it needs a non-ergodic basis.

Comment: Re: "manifestly cannot be true given the evolution must be constrained to energy contours" That's normally not considered as breaking ergodicity, since most often one assumes/requires the system is ergodic "_in the (energetically) available_ phase space".

Comment: ah yes you're right, also the constraint doesn't even hold in the contexts I'm concerned about like canonical ensembles and such